# i need it to see if one number in the list is the same as a number adjacent to it

Tags: excel-formula

i have got two lists of data. i am trying to see if one number in one list is equal to another number in the other list. i did =sum(countif(A1:A10,B1:B10) which did partially work. the issue is i want it to count if the number adjacent to it is the same but this just counts if any number is the same as any number in the two lists.

i tried =SUM(COUNTIF(P2:P10,N2:N10)) and it said that 1 was the same in my list. non of the numbers where the same as the adjacent number but one of the numbers was the same as a number elsewhere in the other list

just to clarify i want a singular formula which shows the amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
=IF(A1:A10<>B1:B10,"Different","Same")
```

or

```
=IF(A1:A10=B1:B10,"Same","Different")
```

Both do the same, the first one checks if the cells are different, the second one if they are the same, but the output should be the same.

You can change the text to whatever you like, or even a number.

---

Additional, as you want just one cell that displays the amount of different values?

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A10<>B1:B10,1,0)
```

This will give you the amount of different cells, replace '<>' with '=' and it'll give you the amount of matching cells.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to show how many are the same in a single cell (preferably there isnt the list of same/different) i'd imagine it would involve =sum

Comment: i found a formula that works but i am wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing it (its searching through 10 rows so ive done it so it checks each individual row). =SUM(COUNTIF(N2,O2),COUNTIF(N3,O3),COUNTIF(N4,O4),COUNTIF(N5,O5),COUNTIF(N6,O6),COUNTIF(N7,O7),COUNTIF(N8,O8),COUNTIF(N9,O9),COUNTIF(N10,O10))

Comment: @Willmeister110 check my added solution, hope that's what you need?